# Why does IE ask if I want to save the password for localhost after trying to logon when running a new MVC 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I am not sure how ASP.NET MVC 3 Authentication works out of the box, but I noticed two odd behaviors when I created a new MVC 3 Web Project.  I did not make a single change.  When I first ran it, I noticed I was signed in as a user from a previous project.  So, I clicked Log Off, and then when I tried to login as another user (TestAdmin) IE gave me the message:

> "Do you want Internet Explorer to
>   remember your password for localhost?"

I would expect it to ask me to save the password for TestAdmin, not localhost.  What's going on behind the scenes?  How can I get it to use the User Account Name instead of the default "localhost"?

Comment: localhost is the hostname you used to browse to the web app, e.g: http://localhost/myWebApp. IE asks if it should store the login information for that server.

Comment: My gut would have told me that the password is not just tied to 'localhost' but also to the port number being used (ie: http://localhost:23434). However, when you start up a new project it will auto-assign a new port number to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to take the initiative to say there is no way to override this message without modifying the Internet Explorer browser executable or dependencies, and why would you want to?

If you think of this from a non-developer perspective, the functionality makes sense because someone will be asked, *"Do you want to save your password for http://www.facebook.com?"*

It would not make sense to the user if it used the application name to say something like, *"Do you want to save your password for FacebookBuild3?"*